# Call to a member function mysql_affected_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php

I've got an error saying

> Call to a member function mysql_affected_rows() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\initializr\search.php on line 189

when I click my submit button.

```
if(isset($_POST['select'])) {
    $studId = $_REQUEST['studid'];

    foreach ($studId as $ch) {
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tbl_tempCand (datetime, names) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '".$ch."')");
        //this is my line 189 error
        if($row->mysql_affected_rows($result)==0) {
            header("Location: registercand.php");
        } else {
            echo "nothing happen";
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: First off, please don't use mysql_* functions, they're officially deprecated. Second, your query seems open to SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements or parametrised queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tbl_tempCand (`datetime`, `names`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '".$ch."')");
                                                    ^ // here was the problem
```

`datetime` is a **RESERVED WORD** in `mysql` and because of that query fails. If you want to use this kind of reserved words as column quote them inside of this ``` `` ```

Change

```
if($row->mysql_affected_rows($result)==0)
```

to

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows > 0)
```

Comment: it got me the same error pointing to if($row->mysql_affected_rows($result)==0) not on my query...

Comment: @PotPot Actually your query fails and it gives you no result and because of that it gives error here `mysql_affected_rows($result)`

Comment: so what should i gonna do, when my query is successful, it would redirect to another form?.. pls gve me some advice sir...

Comment: when your query runs successfully , the affected rows will be greater than 0 so change your condition to `if($row->mysql_affected_rows($result)>0) { //your code }`

Comment: i forgot to change the that line,but still stuck on the same error even i change it, maybe i could find another way to do what i want & hope i could, & still thankful to every1, this site really help me a lot and i ask for your consideration for being so unmindful sometimes, maybe im just over stressed. hope u would consider me again..

Comment: @PotPot have you changed the query with my query.

Comment: @PotPot see the edited answer. Now it will solve your problem.